# IF/ELSE block running everything

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am making a program to run speed/distance/time calculations. This code works when the surrounding "IF %type%==s(...)" statement is removed, but not when I put it back. It seems to run all the lines? Here's the code:

```
@ECHO off
COLOR 0f
TITLE Speed Distance Time Calculator
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

:BEGIN
SET /P type="Calculate speed/distance/time? (S/D/T): "
CLS

IF /I %type%==s (
    SET /P distance="Distance: "
    CLS

    :SDUNITS
    SET /P dUnits="Distance units (mile/m/km):"

    IF /I "%dUnits%"=="mile" (
        SET /a multiply = 0.000621371
    ) ELSE IF /I "%dUnits%"=="m" (
        SET /a multiply = 1
    ) ELSE IF /I "%dUnits%"=="km" (
        SET /a multiply = 0.001
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO "Please type mile/m/km: "
        GOTO SDUNITS
    )

    SET /P time="Time: "
    CLS

    :STUNITS
    SET /P tUnits="Time units (h/m/s):"

    IF /I "%tUnits%" == "h" (
        SET /a divide = 3600
    ) ELSE IF /I "%tUnits%" == "m" (
        SET /a divide = 60
    ) ELSE IF /I "%tUnits%" == "s" (
        SET /a divide = 1
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO "Please type h/m/s: "
        GOTO STUNITS
    )

    FOR /F %%B IN ('powershell !distance! / !time! * !multiply! / !divide!') DO SET total=%%B
) ELSE (
    ECHO "Please type S/D/T"
    GOTO BEGIN
)

ECHO !total!

PAUSE
EXIT
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"%type%"  == "s"`, perhaps?

Comment: Open a command prompt window, type `set /?` and read in output help about __delayed expansion__ which is one more problem in your code.

Comment: also note, that `set /a` works with integers only. (in fact, the dots will lead to syntax errors) As you do calculating with powershell, just use `set multiply=0.001`. NO SPACES around the `=` please! They would be part of your variablenames.

Comment: Batch doesn't have `else if`, just `else`. You have to completely rewrite your code to take that into account.

Comment: @SomethingDark - True there is no formal ELSE IF construct, but the IF logic in the OP's code is perfectly valid. I use that type of construct all the time. For each collective set of IF/ELSE, only one IF is TRUE and fires, else the final naked ELSE fires.

Comment: Having labels in parentheses is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are a couple of major problems here.

1. **Delayed Expansion issues.**  As already stated in the comments above, this is a pretty major problem that you'll need to understand better.  This alone, I think renders this approach with the giant `IF` block with nested `IF` statements impossible in a windows batch program.  You'd probably be better off using `GOTO` (inelegant as it may be):

   ```
   ...
   set /p type="Calculate [S]peed, [D]istance, or [T]ime? "
   if /i %type%=S (goto calcSpeed)
   else if /i %type%=D (goto calcDist)
   else if /i %type%=T (goto calcTime)

   :calcSpeed
   set /p t="Enter the time: "
   :EnterTimeUnits
   set /p tUnits="Enter the time units - [H]ours, [M]inutes, [S]econds: "
   if /i "%tUnits%"=="H" (
       set /a divide=3600
   ) else if /i "%tUnits%"=="M" (
   set /a divide=60
   ) else if /i "%tUnits%"=="S" (
   set /a divide=1
   ) else (
   echo Try again.
   goto EnterTimeUnits
   )
   ...
   ```
2. **Integers only.**  Also mentioned in the comments above, windows batch variables can only handle integers and strings.  No floating point decimal numbers of any kind.  You'll have to rearrange your logic so that you can put your `multiply` value into the powershell command.  Something like:

   ```
   ...
   if /i "%dUnits%"=="mile" (
       for /f %%B IN ('powershell %d%/%t%*0.000621371/%div%') DO SET total=%%B
   ) else if /i "%dUnits%"=="m" (
       for /f %%B IN ('powershell %d%/%t%*1/%div%') DO SET total=%%B
   ) else if /i "%dUnits%"=="km" (
       for /f %%B IN ('powershell %d%/%t%*0.001/%div%') DO SET total=%%B
   ...
   ```

With those out of the way, we can proceed to help with your actual question:

> [The] code works when the surrounding `IF` statement is removed, but not when I put it back.  It seems to run all the lines.

I'm not seeing the issue as you describe.  However, because of the delayed expansion issues in your nested `IF` statements, it does some funny looping, asking for the same input twice.  I think once you deal with those issues, your other problems will clear up.

Troubleshooting:  `CLS` and `@ECHO OFF` are great for keeping your console tidy, but they make troubleshooting/debugging your program very difficult.  Removing those lines will help you see what's going on.